# How do you only tar files in a directory based on a specific file name?

Tags: linux, redhat, tar

I want to create a tar ball and include only the files in the directory that start with a specific filename. For instance I have apples-x.x.x and oranges-x.x.x, and I only want to tar the files beginning with "apple". How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ummm, I may be overlooking something, but how about

```
tar cf /path/tarfile appl*
```

Unless you have directories which are also called `./appl*`, in which case they'll get trawled up, with their contents, that should do it.  If the latter pertains, you can stop that with `--no-recursion`.

Comment: Thanks this is excellent and spot on for what I need to do.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe something like that:

`find / -type f -name "apple*" -exec tar -rf archive.tar '{}' \;`

Its better than `tar cf /path/tarfile appl*` beacause dont archive directory with pattern apple*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will run the tar command multiple times, each time creating a tarfile called archive.tar with one `apple*` file in it; the upshot will be that after the find finishes, you'll have a tarfile containing only the last `apple*` file to be found by `find`.  I'm guessing this isn't what you intend?

Comment: yes my mistake... it should be tar -rf

Comment: now it works (i think) in the way you intend

Comment: @hsatterwhite thx :D

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
find / -type f -name "apple*" -exec tar -cf archive.tar '{}' \+
```

? This way it would pass all file names to tar in a single shot (see *-exec command {} +* on the find man page).

Answer (score 0):

For multiple files with different patterns, one could use

```
find ./ -type f \( -name "apple*" -o -name "orange*" -o -name "berries*" -o -name "lemons*" \) -exec tar -cf archive.tar '{}' \+
```

This is based on the answers from B14D3 and al0, and the link here : https://www.tecmint.com/linux-find-command-to-search-multiple-filenames-extensions/